# How to use the charms mentioned in the Atharva Veda?

Tags: atharva-veda

I want to use the following charms mentioned in Atharva Veda:

[A charm to overthrow a rival and gain strength, dignity, long life, children, and general prosperity](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/av/av10005.htm)

[A Charm to secure various blessings](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/av/av16002.htm)

[To the waters for strength and power](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/av/av01005.htm)

But I don't know how to use those charms. Is it okay if I learned those Mantras and chanted without any Guru, or should I need to go to a person who is already an expert in Atharva Veda?

Comment: In general, any Mantra has to be taken from an able/competent Guru. The Mantra alone can't work, but the Guru's Shakti or "Chaitanya" works. It makes the Mantra work.

Comment: @Vineet The problem here is I am from Tamil Nadu I can find only Guru for Rig, Yajur and Sama Veda.

Comment: It is not the student who finds the guru, it is the guru who finds the student.  There are 2 relevant Q&A's as regards to "Is it okay if I learned those Mantras and chanted without any Guru" and "How do I find Guru". https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18415/vidya-without-a-physical-guru   and https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2394/how-do-i-find-the-right-guru

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vidya without a Physical Guru?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18415/vidya-without-a-physical-guru)